# Search by Location and Keywords

Tags: database, search, indexing, geospatial

I have data set with ~5M entries/rows (~2GB). Every entry contains a location field (lat/lon coordinate-pair) and *n* keyword fields (keyword-1, keyword-2, ... keyword-n). The keyword-fields can all contain multiple keywords, but they are of different importance/"quality".

I need to perform a query on this data set that returns the *k* "best-matching entries for any given combination of (location, {keyword-1, keyword-2, ... keyword-n}), sorted by match quality.

Match quality is determined first by the count of keyword matches of keyword-1 keywords, then keyword-2 keywords, ... then keyword-n keywords and finally the the distance between the entry-location and the search-location

Currently (for n=3 and k=10) this is implemented inside mysql as a table with the location (and btree-indices on lat/lon) and a table for the (again btree-indexed) keywords. To perform the query a join over the 2 tables is done for keyword-1 keywords and the resultset is sorted and cut off, if the result set had less then *k* rows the query is repeated for keyword-2 keywords and so on.

This has worked fairly well so far, but as data and query volume increase, the response times have become worrisome. Currently a query takes about 300ms.

I'm unsure how to proceed next.

The "easy" solution would be to get more machines and spread the queries out over them, but then the data would be spread across multiple machines .. which isn't ideal since the data will have to be kept in sync and the load will have to be balanced and services would need to be discovered/located, etc..

I did look at various in-memory solutions, but none of them offer both location-based and keyword-based search or have mature implementations or can run in single-node mode.

If I were to implement this (arguably simple) search service myself, how do I approach it? Quadtrees/Hilbert-Curves/Geohashes seem easy enough to implement, but getting the memory allocation bit right probably still won't be trivial. And then after that, I'd still need to join the results together with those from the keyword search...

Do any of you have experiences with systems like these? Any recommendations on what to do?

Comment: Something like Elasticsearch could possibly do this.

Comment: @thorstenmüller isn't that too heavyweight a solution? I don't have real documents (i.e. unstructred/schema-free data)

Comment: It's not more heavyweight than say mysql itself. So who cares? I use Elastic (and Apache Solr before) for a lot of stuff where I can leverage some of it's features. Beneath the classical full text search I use it for aggregations and to get statistical data faster and easier than with SQL. Also it's super easy to have it run on several nodes (and it's not much more work than doing some initial config, it will sync and balance etc all by itself.) Really neat and powerful tool. The unstructured thing is only one option, I basically never use that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've done similar with a free-text search index (admittedly in Oracle, not MySQL). We created a new column containing all the reference words and simply told the DB to index it, then all queries were performed on that data. The ordering of it by importance was done afterwards in client code.

The free-text search indexing can set word weights, though this differs on implementation. A quick google says MySql has a [full-text search index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) which can set weighting against words used in your query.

I don't know if that helps your specific case, but its a good place to start. Its also fast and flexible for more powerful queries you might use later (we applied a custom double-metaphone algorithm for sounds-like or misspelled searching for example)